# Scanning a binary against YARA rules dictionary

Tags: malware, python, scan, static-analysis, yara

I have found a malware binary, Which i am curious to see what patterns has been found from this file. Also i have a collection of ~1000 ioc's and yara-rule's related to Malwares and RAT's. I used [Loki](https://www.nextron-systems.com/loki/), [yara-gui](http://sigint9.github.io/yaragui/), The [yara64](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/umip8ndplytwzj1/AADdLRsrpJL1CM1vPVAxc5JZa?dl=0) (i don't remember the link source) itself and some other tools but non of them are capable of scanning multiple rule's against a single file. Already written a simple python code (It scan multiple times, Not complicated) and it is so slow and messy:

```
import os

rules = raw_input("Rules Folder: ")
mal = raw_input("Malicious File: ")
paths = [os.path.join(rules,fn) for fn in next(os.walk(rules))[2]]

for i in range(0,len(paths)):
    os.system('yara64.exe "'+paths[i]+'" "'+mal+'" --no-warnings -f -e -m >> output.txt')
```

So **how do you scan your sample against multiple yara-rule's?** Any specific or public(free/paid) **tool** or **script** which is efficient?

Answer (score 1):

YARA allows you to specify multiple rules files to be used (as the latest version).

```
yara64.exe path/rule/file1 path/rule/file2 path/rule/file3 malwareFile
```

I don't know what the limit to the number of rule file paths you can specify is in a single YARA invocation, but this should make it considerably easier to script.

Comment: Nice, This is in the newer version. But again we have to write a script to do it multiple times.

Comment: I don't think there's a perfect solution, but this may speed up your execution 10x-100x.